# Forming a data set from an Object

Tags: javascript, performance, ecmascript-6

I am trying to construct data sets from an Object which I receive as a response from an API.

The data is in the format.

```
let assets = [
  {count: 1, skills: ["teach", "play"]},
  {count: 1, skills: ["write", "surf"]},
  {count: 2, skills: ["run", "teach"]},
  {count: 3, skills: ["teach", "run", "hike"]}
]
```

Forming an array of unique skills from the above response.

```
let unique = ["teach", "play", "write", "surf", "run", "hike"]
```

I constructed an array of object by running.

```
let finalObj = {};
unique.map( (skill) => {
  finalObj[skill] = assets.filter( asset => asset.skills.includes(skill) )
  .map( asset => ({skill: skill, count: asset.count}) );  
})
```

This is how it looks like after running the code.

**May be this is an extra step which could be avoided.**

```
finalObj = {
  teach: [{skill: teach, count: 1},{skill: teach, count: 2}, {skill: teach, count: 3}],
  play: [{skill: play, count: 1}],
  write: [{skill: write, count: 1}],
  surf: [{skill: surf, count: 1}],
  run: [{skill: run, count: 2}, {skill: run, count: 3}],
  hike: [{skill: hike, count: 3}]
}
```

I am expecting my final data set to be.

```
let data0 = [ 
  {skill: 'teach', count: 2},
  {skill: 'play', count: 1},
  {skill: 'write', count: 1},
  {skill: 'surf', count: 1},
  {skill: 'run', count: 2},
  {skill: 'hike', count: 3}
]

let data1 = [
  {skill: 'teach', count: 2},
  {skill: 'run', count: 3}
]

let data2 = [
  {skill: teach, count: 3}
]

// To find the max length of all array in finalObj
let tempLen = 0;
Object.keys(finalObj).forEach((key) => {
  if (tempLen > finalObj[key].length) {
    tempLen = tempLen
  } else {
    tempLen = finalObj[key].length
  }
})
// returns 3 - expected
```

This is to show a way of creating variable inside a for loop which uses the value of current iteration in variable name. Not related to actual code.

```
for (let i = 0; i < tempLen; i++) {
  let str ="data"+ i+" = []";
  eval(str).push(i)
}
// returns data0=[0], data1=[1], data2=[2] - expected
```

This is to show that expected result was achieved by hard coding variable name and array index. Not a scenario in my app.

```
let sampleData = []
Object.keys(finalObj).forEach(key => 
  sampleData.push(finalObj[key][0])
)
// returns expected data
```

When I try this with an actual scenario.

```
for (let i = 0; i < tempLen; i++) {
  let str ="data"+ i+" = []";
  Object.keys(finalObj).forEach((key) => {
    eval(str).push(finalObj[key][i])
  })
}
// not expected result
```

Comment: Why do you want three *variables* instead of an array with three items?

Comment: Aside from having three variables, why on earth would you use `eval`?

Comment: @briosheje in order to be able to assign three variables...

Comment: question is confusing. Keep Input data and Expected output only in the question.

Comment: @kaleem, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval! (add a ! to the end of the link)

Comment: @VLAZ, yeah, an array with three items is fine too.

Comment: @murli2308 yeah, I agree. I've been reading and re-reading this question ever since I commented, so for about 10 minutes now and I am barely able to grasp what it's about. The code shown addresses the requirements very indirectly - *describe* them better. It all depends on some variable called `assets` that's not actually shown and I had to look at three code blocks to even understand what it's about. List what `assets` is and the expected output and *why* that is the expected output.

Comment: @assoron, with `eval`, I am able to create var name inside a for loop with current index concatenated with a string. Eg: 'var = data1' where 1 could `i`

Comment: @murli2308, I will post the question again with just the input and expected output. Sorry for the long post where i have included the code which I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've use `data` object to store the desired arrays, in key iteration of the object, there would be a check to avoid `undefined` elements.You need to avoid `eval`:

```js
let assets = [{
    count: 1,
    skills: ["teach", "play"]
  },
  {
    count: 1,
    skills: ["write", "surf"]
  },
  {
    count: 2,
    skills: ["run", "teach"]
  },
  {
    count: 3,
    skills: ["teach", "run", "hike"]
  }
];

let unique = ["teach", "play", "write", "surf", "run", "hike"];

let finalObj = {};
unique.map((skill) => {
  finalObj[skill] = assets.filter(asset => asset.skills.includes(skill))
    .map(asset => ({
      skill: skill,
      count: asset.count
    }));
});

let tempLen = 0;
Object.keys(finalObj).forEach((key) => {
  if (tempLen > finalObj[key].length) {
    tempLen = tempLen
  } else {
    tempLen = finalObj[key].length
  }
})

let data = {};

for (let i = 0; i < tempLen; i++) {
  data["data" + i] = [];
  Object.keys(finalObj).forEach((key) => {
    if (finalObj[key][i])
      data["data" + i].push(finalObj[key][i])
  })
}

console.log(data);
```